# Jealous, Lying, or unAmerican

Tags: word, cipher, visual

I opened my email today to find this odd image.

[image: whirl of letters]

I suddenly had a strange craving, which fortunately I was able to satisfy outside my local Starbucks—-I happened to be driving by literally as the stand was being set up, and immediately found the next parking space and walked over, getting there before the folks who ended up forming a queue behind me. It's always nice being able to skip the line....

Anyways.  **What is it that I had to have?**

Now that you know what I have here, you know you're jealous.  If not, you're either lying, or unAmerican. *You monster*.

---

<sub>Hint:</sub>

> <sub>Always look before you leap!</sub>

Comment: Don't worry, I won't judge.

Comment: Rot13(Gur fcveny pbhyq cbvag ng Terra Neebj (be Terra Ynagrea?) sebz gur Whfgvpr Yrnthr bs Nzrevpn (jubfr vavgvnyf ner gur pncvgny yrggref sebz gur gvgyr). Zber boivbhfyl, gur jbeqf "guvf jnl" vaqvpngr va juvpu qverpgvba gb ernq gur yrggref.)

Comment: i can see the phrases - 'THIS WAY' and 'WE BUY' also if you hover over the image the tooptip will give you the order of the letters inside out

Comment: might need a hint

Comment: For easier analysis, here's the letters: "S V S W R K H G J U O E F P V I V H K W T C R J R M M P U H W E Y Y N T Q F G M M Q R I W M G Y G W B K N R A U M M I V R R C U U U Q L T D N W I Z E I Z I A I C Z O W D S V H T W E B U Y X A Y Z Z W I Y A W S I H T" @CodeBoyCode

Comment: Rot13(Abg na nafjre, ohg onfrq ba gur gvzvat va Nzrevpn, gur pbzzbanyvgl bs cbchc ybpngvbaf bhgfvqr bs pbssrr fubcf, naq abg yvxvat gurz orvat haNzrevpna, gur svefg guvat V gubhtug bs vf Tvey Fpbhg Pbbxvrf - naq abj V jnag fbzr!)

Comment: rot13(Jbaqrevat jung unccraf jura lbh fhcre-vzcbfr gur Fgneohpxf ybtb bire gur vzntr nobir. Zvtug or gung gur juvgr-fcnprf erirny pregnva yrggref, juvpu zvtug sbez zber pburfvir jbeqf)

Comment: nvm, it's just a big incoherent mess

Comment: Maybe it's alphabet soup ;)

Comment: Also important to note that all the letters of the alphabet do appear at least once

Comment: I imagine the edit by OP has confirmed the comment by @PartyHatPanda

Comment: @nine9 That may be - but if so I still am unsure of how to actually solve the puzzle!

Comment: Sturgeon’s Law holds here. But his estimate is almost 1¾% low. This may or may not help at all.

Comment: Sturgeon's Law +1.75 seems to point to rot13(Gur nafjre vf 9 punenpgref naq TVEYFPBHG, ohg "FXVC gur yvar" znxrf zr guvax bs gnxvat bar punenpgre rirel 12 naq gung trgf zr abguvat.)

Comment: @arbitrahj has a couple of great insights here. What may be missing is one last good idea to replace 12 not-so-good ...

Comment: I'm definitely un-American. Problem solved.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  *...you monster.* ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the hint's advice to

> look before we leap,

let us begin

> at the outermost T

and then

> repeatedly advance by N places where N is the alphabet-position of the letter we're currently at.

We get

> THINMINTS.

Yum!

Comment: Facepalm! I did this but started with the I after This Way! :-( GJ!

Comment: aaahhhhhhh. Well done! I was sitting with this for a while, couldn't get the key. And strangely I was thinking about minty cookies the whole time...